# How to express in Jackson injection of original json string into a field?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

There is a JSON string `""" {"a": 1, "b": "hello"} """`.

I would like to create a model, containing "a", "b" and "originalJson".

```
class MyModel{

    public int a;
    public String b;
    public String originalJson;
} 

void test1(){
    var payload = """ {"a": 1, "b": "hello"} """;

    // how to apply Jackson here?
    MyModel model = magicParse(payload, MyModel.class);

    assertEquals(1, model.a);
    assertEquals("hello", model.b);
    assertEquals(payload, model.originalJson);
}
```

And if we expand it to a more wide application

```
void test2(){
    var payload = """ [
          {"a": 1, "b": "hello"},
          {"a": 2, "b": "bye"}
    ]
    """;

    // how to apply Jackson here?
    MyModel[] models = magicParse(payload, MyModel[].class);

    var firstModel = model[0]
    assertEquals(1, firstModel.a);
    assertEquals("hello", firstModel.b);
    assertEquals("""{"a": 1, "b": "hello"}""", firstModel.originalJson);


    var secondModel = model[2]
    assertEquals(2, secondModel.a);
    assertEquals("bye", secondModel.b);
    assertEquals("""{"a": 2, "b": "bye"}""", secondModel.originalJson);
}
```

Is there a natural way to do it in Jackson (annotations, configurations, ...)?

Comment: I would say your only option is using a custom deserializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried several solutions with custom deserializers, but looks like they require a lot of code blurring the main intention. The basic problem I see is that in deserializer we have access to `JsonParser`, which is stateful and maintains "one-pass" algorithm, so it is not possible to fetch a JSON subtree/substring from it without interfering with normal parsing process.

Another one approach is much more readable, although there could be a performance impact as we deserialize payload twice.
The idea is to get `JsonNode` and using it deserialize model and make further transformations: passing the root node after basic deserialization and before returning the result.

```
// utility for mapping
public static <T, R> R readValue(
    String json,
    Class<T> clazz,
    BiFunction<T, JsonNode, R> transformValue
){
    JsonNode node = getObjectMapper().readValue(json, JsonNode.class);
    T value = mapper.treeToValue(node, clazz);
    return transformValue.apply(value, node);
}


// concrete usage
MyModel getModel(String payload){
    return readValue(
      payload, 
      MyModel.class, 
      (m, node) -> {
          m.payload = node.toString(); 
          return m;
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObjectMapper.readTree()`:

```
private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

public MyModel magicParse(String payload) 
        throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode root = MAPPER.readTree(payload);
    int a = root.get("a").asInt();
    String b = root.get("b").asText();
    return new MyModel(a, b, payload);
}
```

You also need a constructor for `MyModel` (or setters depending on your case):

```
public class MyModel {

    public int a;
    public String b;
    public String originalJson;

    MyModel(int a, String b, String originalJson) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.originalJson = originalJson;
    }

}
```